# Unit Testing a controller

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, controller

There is a project that turnover to me, now my task is to make a unit test for the controller. I've tried to search some tutorials from the net,
This is a method from the controller this is what i found: 

1. http://developer.teradata.com/viewpoint/reference/viewpoint-pdk-cookbook/how-to-create-unit-tests-for-controllers

2. http://www.java-tutorial.ch/software-testing/easymock-tutorial

 
 The links above doesn't fill the glass. I'm new to `Unit Testing`, below is a method from the controller 
 **Controller:**

```
 private boolean insertNewUser( String name, String username, String password, String email, String userType,
                                   String team, String[] projectid,HttpSession session )
    {
        UsersDAO usersDAO = new UsersDAO();
        ArrayList<Integer> projects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        boolean insert;

        String sessionType = ( String ) session.getAttribute( SessionUtility.SESSION_TYPE );
        if( sessionType.equalsIgnoreCase( SessionUtility.TYPE_SUPERADMIN ) )
        {
            if( userType.equalsIgnoreCase( SessionUtility.TYPE_ADMIN ) ||
                userType.equalsIgnoreCase( SessionUtility.TYPE_SUPERADMIN ) )
            {
                if( projectid != null )
                {
                    for( int i = 0; i < projectid.length; i++ )
                    {
                        projects.add( Integer.parseInt( projectid[i] ) );
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        if( !projects.contains( Integer.parseInt( ( String ) session.getAttribute( SessionUtility.SESSION_PROJECT ) ) ) )
        {
            projects.add( Integer.parseInt( ( String ) session.getAttribute( SessionUtility.SESSION_PROJECT ) ) );
        }
        insert = usersDAO.insertNewUser( name, username, password, email, userType, team, projects );

        return insert;

    }
```

**Question:** How do i make a Unit Test for a controller? example method is above. 
If you need more clarification please comment.

**UPDATE:** Easymock example would be great

Comment: are you asking how to use junit or how a unit test should look like?

Comment: i have an idea of how to use a junit but to use it on a controller i don't know how would i do that.

Comment: please see my post below @newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make use of Spring's unit testing and create something like this (http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

    @Before
    private void setUp(){
        //init variables here
    }

    @Test
    private boolean insertNewUser(){
//initialize this variables:

 String name, String username, String password, String email, String userType,
  String team, String[] projectid,HttpSession session ;

        String sessionType = ( String ) session.getAttribute( SessionUtility.SESSION_TYPE );
        assertEquals(sessionType, SessionUtility.TYPE_SUPERADMIN);
        assertEquals(userType, SessionUtility.TYPE_ADMIN);
        assertEquals(userType, SessionUtility.TYPE_SUPERADMIN);
        assertNotNull(projectId);

    }
```

Comment: Can i test the controller on an isolation?

Comment: point of unit testing, is it should be tested on isolation. you initialize those needed in the method tagged by @Before

Comment: SessionUtility.TYPE_ADMIN is from a request, how would i mock that request? If i'm not mistaken should i really mock that? sorry i'm new to this stuff

Comment: you can use Mockito for mocking these kind of stuff or you can just provide dummy values. or what the values you assume, or what they should be

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [grails.test.ControllerUnitTestCase](http://www.grails.org/Testing+Controllers) and create something like this:

```
class ControllerTests extends grails.test.ControllerUnitTestCase {
void testInsert() {
    controller.params.query = "Insert Query";
    controller.insert();
    assertEquals ("expected result", controller.response.contentAsString);
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a setup needed before i can use grails? or connection to database? can i mock the conenction?